# Why Android Studio is showing errors "everywhere in code" after last update?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Yesterday I have updated my AndroidStudio IDE and after that I see strange error everywhere, even on fresh project:
[image]

there is also message:

> Cannot access 'android.app.Activity' which is a supertype of 'pl.testapp.MainActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies. Cannot access 'java.lang.Object' which is a supertype of 'pl.testapp.MainActivity'. Check your module classpath for missing or conflicting dependencies.

I can build project but writing code where everything is underlined is horrible ;p. I have already tried to reinstall IDE but with no result. Have you ever experienced that?

Comment: Check if JDK and Android SDK path are properly configured in your android studio.

Comment: there is an "invalidate caches and restart" option. try it!

Comment: Unfortunately, none of Your suggestions work

Answer (score 3):

For anyone else running into this in 2021 and beyond.
I found that one of my Sdk's was corrupt.
To fix:

1. File -> Project Structure (or Cmd + ;)
2. Modules on left hand side
3. Properties tab
4. Change "Compile Sdk Version" to a different one

For me, changing this made all the errors disappear.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens when the IDE's executable is moved to another folder. Close the IDE and rename the folder containing the IDE settings to recreate it.
In my case the path to the settings folder was:
/home/myLinuxUser/.config/Google/AndroidStudio2020.3
So I renamed "AndroidStudio2020.3" to "AndroidStudio2020.3__OLD". After that, go to the IDE again and open your project.

Comment: Can confirm this fixed it for me, i had just uninstalled and reinstalled android studio when this issue appeared too.

Answer (score 1):

This issue occurs only when all the dependencies will not be dowloaded after opening the android studio that's why it show the error .

Follow the steps to resolve the issue
Step 1. Clean the project
[Clean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzzJV.png)
Step 2. Rebuild the projet.
[Rebuild](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbrtv.png)

This issue will be resolve

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that expected imports aren't available on the classpath for what ever reason:

[image]

One cause could be that the InelliJ IDEA cache got messed up.
Solution: Go to `File->Invalidate Caches / Restart` and check if the problem has been solved after restart.

Other cause could be that you deleted your SDK. Check if your Android-SDK ist still configured properly:

[image]

Let me know, if I helped you!

Comment: Thank You for Your answer. I have checked all suggestions... SDK, JDK seems to be ok. "Invalidate caches" gives no effect.

Comment: The `android.os.Bundle` class in in the `android.jar`. That file should be part of the sdk. Could you check if that file is still part of your sdk?

Answer (score 0):

OK I have already fixed this issue. I had unninstalled AndroidStudio, deleted all folders related to IDE and also deleted SDK folder, after that installed everything fresh once again. That was very strange, that was the first time for me when Update broke IDE... Thank You all of You :)